# Database Design for Relational Database

Tags: postgresql, vert.x

I'm developing an Enterprise application using vert.x and Postgres, with huge database, typically around 100 tables, each consisting between 2M to 100M records. Each record has around 20 attributes and has a ts_vector column for text search with some attributes linked to other tables.

I have created indexes both using clusters and single indexes. Generally, a select statement takes around 600-1000ms where as an insert statement takes around 100ms to 1000000ms or higher.

I know that indexing takes a lot of time while inserting and understand the consequences, if I remove indexing, selecting takes a lot of time.

For few reasons, my insert queries are taking a lot of time. How will I solve this problem, some architects suggested me to separate database by read and write server.

Is there any design that I need to implement to solve this problem??

Comment: Poor title. Edit to describe your *specific* technical issue.

Comment: There is no magical button to make everything fast. You need to ask specific questions, but be aware that speeding up one thing may well slow down another.

Comment: how is your status with separate read/write server?

Comment: Performance is pretty much better with read/write server. Have apache kafka server listening to write server and pushing changes to read server (Using debezuim)